# Insertar Js en un botón en Wordpress o menu de navegación

Tags: wordpress

Tengo un código Js para insertar en una página de Wordpress. Me gustaría ponerlo como un elemento del menú que cuando hicieses clic se abriese el pop-up de la llamada, o sino también ponerlo en un botón flotante.

El Theme en cuestión me deja insertar el código JS, pero, ¿cómo hago la llamada desde el botón del menú o desde el botón flotante para que cuando hagas clic te abra ese Js?

El Js en cuestión es:

```
<div class="content-boton-c2c" data-sticky_parent="" id="botonclicktocall_2">
<div class="btn-c2c" data-sticky_column="" >
<!-- Click to call STARTS HERE -->
<script id="c2c-button" src="//apps.netelip.com/clicktocall/api/js/c2c.js?btnid=350&atk=53abe49f8e103cab75bbdca1f4b9fc04" type="text/javascript"></script><!-- Click to call ENDS HERE -->
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si puedes insertar tu js y usas jquery, no hay más que hacer:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("clase_o_id").click(function() {
            alert("Acciones a realizar");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Dónde pone `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` es así porque `$(function() {` como siempre, no funcionará en wordpress.

Dónde pone `clase_o_id` tienes que poner la clase del botón, por ejemplo, `.boton` o el id, por ejemplo, `#boton`.

Cambia el alert por el código que quieras ejecutar al hacer click.